# Map() not a funtion when calling MVC end point using react

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller

Hi I am learning react and trying to call an MVC endpoint from react and display the result in a table.
The MVC endpoint returns a json data like the below format,

```
{  
"Rooms":[  
  {  
     "Types":[  
        {  
           "Type":"Apple",
           "Available":"3",
           "Total":"31"
        }
     ],
     "id":"R1",
     "
  },
  {  
     "Types":[  
        {  
           "Type":"Orange",
           "Available":"4",
           "Total":"40"
        }
     ],
     "id":"R2",         
  },

  {  
     "Types":[  
        {  
           "Type":"Apple",
           "Available":"25",
           "Total":"30"
        },
        {  
           "Type":"Mango",
           "Available":"23",
           "Total":"36"
        }
     ],
     "id":"R3",         
  },
  {  
     "Types":[  
        {  
           "Type":"Apple",
           "Available":"23",
           "Total":"36"
        },
        {  
           "Type":"Mango",
           "Available":"23",
           "Total":"36"
        },
        {  
           "Type":"Orange",
           "Available":"23",
           "Total":"36"
        }
     ],
     "id":"R4",

   }

]
}
```

I have come up with my limited knowledge and googling something like the below,

```
"use strict";

var React = require('react');


var List= React.createClass({

// getInitialState: function(){
//     return({
//         rooms: []
//     });
// },
state: {
    rooms: []
},

componentWillMount: function() {
    fetch('https://dummyMVCendpoint.com/json')
    .then(res => res.json())        
    .then(Rooms => {
        this.setState({rooms: Rooms})
    })        
  },
render(){
    var createRoomRow = function(rooms) {
        return (
            <tr key={rooms.id}>
                <td>{rooms.id}</td>
                <td>{rooms.Types}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    };
    return (          


         <div>

         //<p>{JSON.stringify(this.state) }</p>


         {<table className="table"> 
         <thead>
             <th>RoomID</th>
             <th>Types</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            {this.state.map(createRoomRow, this)}
         </tbody>
         </table>             
     </div>
    );      
   }
});

module.exports=List;
```

Now I want to display in the table the ID,available/total Types. I do understand the above jsx does not do exactly what I want.

But I am also getting an error,Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's few suggestions:

1. Check if you

```
    fetch('https://dummyMVCendpoint.com/json')
    .then(res => res.json())        
    .then(Rooms => {
    console.log(Rooms) // make sure you are getting the right data
        this.setState({rooms: Rooms})
    })
```

2. Replace this

```
{this.state.map(createRoomRow, this)}
```

with

```
{createRoomRow}
```

and then

```
var createRoomRow = this.state.rooms.map(rooms => {
        return (
            <tr key={rooms.id}>
                <td>{rooms.id}</td>
                <td>{rooms.Types}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    });
```

3. Use `getInitialState`
   Altogether

```
"use strict";

var React = require('react');


var List= React.createClass({

componentWillMount: function() {
    fetch('https://dummyMVCendpoint.com/json')
    .then(res => res.json())        
    .then(Rooms => {
        this.setState({rooms: Rooms})
    })        
  },
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      rooms: []
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    var renderExtraRows = (dataList) => dataList.map(list => {
      return (
        <div>
          <span>{list.Type}</span>
          <span>{list. Total}</span>
        </div>        
      );
    });
    var createRoomRow = this.state.rooms.map(item => {
        return (
            <tr key={item.id}>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
                <td>{renderExtraRows(item.Types)}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    });
    return (          


         <div>

         {<table className="table"> 
           <thead>
               <th>RoomID</th>
               <th>Types</th>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              {createRoomRow}
           </tbody>
           </table>}            
     </div>
    );      
   }

});

module.exports=List;
```

Comment: I am getting the Rooms object in the console. But when I tried your code I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rooms' of null"

Comment: ah, I overlooked `React.createClass`, so you cant use `state: {}` in createClass. In ES5, you have to use getInitialState.  I updated the answer, let me know if this works.
Working example https://jsfiddle.net/jo1gdhq4/

Comment: that works, but can I bother you with one more question. As you can see in json, the type is another array. So how can I show it like under the Types column, Oranges 5/10 Mango 3/20 etc

Comment: Sure, so `Types` gonna be always an array with one one object? or it can have multiple objects?

Comment: So it is going to be as in the example in the question, can have multiple objects or single. So for same r1 there is apple, for r3 there is apple and mango and so on.

Comment: I updated the answer. The idea is to map an array wherever you have an array to show data. React only can render a string, array of react elements or string.
If this help, accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks that helped, I have marked it as answer, but could you please update the line  var renderExtraRows = (dataList) => data.map(list => { to  var renderExtraRows = (dataList) => dataList.map(list => {.  I am sure that is what you meant.

Comment: @ Subhendu, I have raised another question related to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810915/navigate-from-1-page-to-another-on-table-row-click-using-react.